# Gzip not zipping all CSS & JS

Tags: php, performance, compression, gzip

My hosting provider does not use htaccess to enable gzip. Their support told me to change my HTML file to PHP and add the following at the top:

```
<?php ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); ?>
```

However, after using [gzipWTF](http://gzipwtf.com) to find out if my site is making full use of gzip, there are a number of assets listed - save only 3 - that are not being gzipped.

If you would, go to [gzipWTF](http://gzipwtf.com/), and enter my URL:
"http://justinjwilson.com".

Check 'details' as an option. Why is it that most of my JS and CSS files are not gzipped? An easy PHP solution would be best. Remember, I can't use htaccess to enable gzip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're out of luck with the one-liner. Adding that line to the top of the now-PHP  HTML page is going to cause PHP to handle the gzip-ing of the page content. But *only* that page. It has no impact on the external files, because it doesn't process them in any way. (Separate files are separate GET requests from the browser; PHP knows nothing about them).

So you need a solution that will allow PHP to handle the gzip-ing of all of your content. A relatively simple solution would be to write a separate PHP page that would handle the delivery of *all* of your external files. Something like `/resource.php?r=myscript.js`.  This php script would have the `"ob_gzhandler"` turned on at the top, and then would simply *open* the file, and echo it out.

Comment: To add to this, IE6 gets very unhappy if you gzip css content (or was it js content?).

Comment: I see. That's good to know. So, how would I call this PHP file? Is there a snippet that would do exactly what you're saying? In any case, I need to compile my CSS and JS files down to 2 or 3, but I'm not sure what to do next with the PHP code..

Comment: How did I miss checking your answer after all this time...? Sorry about that!